# type "hstore" is only a shell

Tags: postgresql, audit-logging

I am trying to setup automatic audit Logging in Postgres Using Triggers and Trigger Functions. For this i want to create the table logged_actions in audit schema. When i run the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit.logged_actions
(
    event_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('audit.logged_actions_event_id_seq'::regclass),
    schema_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    table_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    relid oid NOT NULL,
    session_user_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    action_tstamp_tx timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    action_tstamp_stm timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    action_tstamp_clk timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    transaction_id bigint,
    application_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    client_addr inet,
    client_port integer,
    client_query text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    action text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    row_data hstore,
    changed_fields hstore,
    statement_only boolean NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT logged_actions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (event_id),
    CONSTRAINT logged_actions_action_check CHECK (action = ANY (ARRAY['I'::text, 'D'::text, 'U'::text, 'T'::text]))
)
```

I have already created the extension "hstore" and query is not executed and error message appears stating that

> ERROR:  type "hstore" is only a shell LINE 17:     row_data hstore

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider using `jsonb` instead

Comment: Seems like something went wrong creating the extension. What do you see in `\dx` in `psql`? What version is this?

Comment: hstore version is 1.7. i have added screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

That's a cryptic way of saying [the hstore extension isn't loaded](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8669.1315326407%40sss.pgh.pa.us). You need to `create extension hstore` before you can use it.

Note that [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) more-or-less makes hstore obsolete.